# Value of type '[Book]?' has no member 'append'

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an array with the following structure

```
["test": [Book1, Book2, Book3], "test4": [Book4, Book5]]
```

I initialized the array -

```
var bookCourses = [String: [Book]]()
```

When I try to add a Book to it, it gives me anerror

`bookCourses["test1"].append(book)` ==> Value of type '[Book]?' has no member 'append'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `bookCourses["test1", default: []].append(book)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the way that you are instantiating `var bookCourses = [String: [Book]]()` causes `bookCourses["test1"]` to be `nil`

A simple way to resolve this issue would be to do a check for `nil` before appending, such as:

```
if bookCourses["test1"] == nil {
    bookCourses["test1"] = [book]
} else {
    bookCourses["test1"]?.append(book)
}
```

Comment: Check my comment on OP post

Comment: This is how you would solve this issue before Swift 4 Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value. I would recommend using the approach showed on my comment

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this :

`course["test1", default: []].append(Book(name: "OK", isbn: "OK"))`

Comment: `test1` Book array might not exist. You need to provide a default value

Comment: Yes, you are right. It might not exist, I edit my answer