# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Int]' with an index of type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code. When it runs, it triggers the error : Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Int]' with an index of type 'String?'

Can someone please help

```
self.books = self.books.filter { $0.completed[MUser.sharedInstance.getUserId()] ?? 0 > 0 }
```

completed is declared as

```
var completed = [String : Int]()
```

Comment: `getUserId()` is obviously an optional. The error says the key must be non-optional. Basically it's the same issue as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196762/value-of-type-book-has-no-member-append).

Comment: ah thank you! do you happen to know how to copy an array?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost What do you mean, "copy" an array? They are already [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/9607863).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates, that `MUser.sharedInstance.getUserId()` returns an optional.
You need to unwrap this:

```
self.books = self.books.filter {  
  guard let userID = MUser.sharedInstance.getUserId() else { return false }
  return $0.completed[userID] ?? 0 > 0 
}
```